# How to deploy a web service to amazon EC2?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, amazon-ec2

i've just created a web application and deployed it to Amazon EC2 , but now i want to create a java web service and deploy it to instance in Amazon AWS to be able to use it in my Application

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Deploying a web service on EC2 is no different to deploying a web service on any other server?

Comment: @codeghost  in  creating a java web service i use WSDL link in The Client Project which is always a local link starts with localhost:8080........  !! . what is the URL i'll use when creating AWS Web Project that uses my service ??

Comment: If you're running (and always will be) the web service and web app on the same machine then you can use localhost (although wouldn't need 8080) just the same. However, you should really decouple your components, the URL to the web service should be in a properties file, with one properties file per environment, which can then be auto filtered by your build tool such as Maven. If you're auto-gen'ing code based off the WSDL then you can include a local copy of the WSDL in your binary and then control the actual URL with config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible configurations. This can be one of them:

1. Start the application server (probably tomcat) with AJP enabled.
2. Use the apache HTTP server JK module to connect the webserver to the Tomcat application.
3. Deploy your web application on the application server and make it generate the WSDL using the external domain name or ip. For example: http://www.domain.com/application/service
4. Make sure that the Amazon firewall has the port 80 open for that instance.
5. If you use domain name, make your DNS point to that host.